# Difference between Maximum a posteriori and penalized likelihood

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, regularization

Can anyone explain to me the difference between penalised likelihood and maximum a posteriori?

I read a paper where the likelihood function is

$$L(\theta_1, \theta_2,\theta_3 ; x)=f(x|\theta_1, \theta_2) f(\theta_2|\theta_1,\theta_3)f(\theta_3)$$
or
$$\ell(\theta_1, \theta_2,\theta_3 ; x)=\log(f(x|\theta_1, \theta_2)) +\log(f(\theta_2|\theta_1,\theta_3))+\log(f(\theta_3))$$

and the authors say they use maximum penalised likelihood to find $\widehat\Theta$. I thought that would be maximum a posteriori and penalised likelihood would use a likelihood function of the form.
$$\ell(\Theta ; x)=\log(f(x|\Theta)) - \lambda g(\Theta)$$

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know if this can be of any help, but - for example - quadratic loglikelihood penalization (squared $L_2$ norm) corresponds to having independent normal  priors on the model parameters. I don't know the deatils of the paper you're referring to, but it's definitely not impossible to "exploit" PL for that purpose - Or maybe I've misunderstood your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Frequentism and priors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29835/frequentism-and-priors)

Comment: The function you produce is not a likelihood because of the extra functions of the parameters at the end.